# Will path code in php work the same from cron?

Tags: cron, php

Will php code which includes paths to files ( in a sub folder at the same location as the php script ) still work when the php script is run from a crontab ?

My php code reads a text file from the 'ref_files' sub-folder. Works 100% when executing the php from my PC browser :

```
$SettingsFile = "./ref_files/push1.txt";
$extData = fopen($SettingsFile, "r");
    while ($line = fgets($extData, 2048)){ //reads the file line by line
        echo $line . "<br>";
    }
fclose($extData);
```

Will this break when the script is run from the crontab ( which I believe executes from a different location ? )

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
Arm v7
OMV 4.1.35.1
Debian 9 Stretch
PHP 7.0.33
Nginx 1.10.3

EDIT : Looks like the following is a solution :

```
$CodeRoot = dirname(__FILE__);

$SettingsFile = "$CodeRoot/ref_files/push1.txt";
$extData = fopen($SettingsFile, "r");
    while ($line = fgets($extData, 2048)){ //reads the file line by line
        echo $line . "<br>";
    }
fclose($extData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cron job will have to `cd` to the right directory first.

eg have something like this as the "command" part of the `crontab` entry.

```
( cd /path/to/php/script/directory ; php myscript.php )
```

Comment: is it possible to code something in the php itself, because I may want to move the code to a different server, and may not be able to control the cron file ?

Comment: I do not understand the `cd`, just make the call on the file with full path.

Comment: Also, I do not understand the necessity for a subshell, please elaborate.

Comment: The code as originally written would look for a file in the current directory, not in the directory that the program lived in.  The `cd` ensures they're the same.  The `(...)` is just stuff I do 'cos it lets me do stuff like `(...) >> /tmp/mylogfile 2>&1` so it can capture the output of `cd` and `myscript`